# Searching in an SVN repository

Tags: svn, search, repository

We have a large SVN repository at work, with probably a few hundred projects spread around the repository. Everything in sorted folders etc etc. I am just wondering if there is any way to search it for files/folders? Or at least list all directories, then I could at the very least CTRL+F it in my editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the entire Subversion repository to your workstation, and do the search there.

I wrote an Eclipse plug-in that extended Subclipse and added a search function.  Since the plug-in has to export every file to my workstation to do the search, it takes a long time.

Comment: Since the repository is so huge I was hoping to avoid this.

I know this can be possible using SharpSVN, but then I'd be making something from scratch. Will probably go that way over the weekend given that no answers are found.

Comment: I'm not able to search the repo *history*, am I?

Comment: Using SharpSVN library? Well, theoretically you should be able I guess. Looping through all files on all revisions could take a while though. 

I assume this is what you meant?

I'll make the program over the weekend if I've got time and throw it on github. Is the repo history search a feature request? :)

It's just a file searcher by the way.

Comment: @hallizh: My process just loops through the files on HEAD, since most people want to find which class contains the search term.  But yes, it takes 3 hours to go through our entire Subversion library.